# Order of numpy list from imported text files

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, text-files

As a follow up of my previous post [(sort data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003630/order-of-files-from-a-folder-as-read-from-python) I want to find out why my numpy array does not "add" the new data as read from the folder. The  previous post solved my problem in reading the files in the right order, but then when I read the data, from each file, and add them in a  numpy array - the resulting array does not have the data in the specified order. 
For example reading the files:

```
0129A.txt

0201A.txt

0210A.txt

0215A.txt
```

in my folder are read from the code correctly (see listing below) but the end product, my_array (seen in the code) does not have the contents of each file in the right order.
Here is my sample code:

```
datadirectory = '/media/DATA'
os.chdir(datadirectory)
listing = sorted(os.listdir(datadirectory))
my_array = np.zeros(shape=(0,3))

for infile in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    dataset = open(infile).readlines()
    data = np.genfromtxt(dataset, usecols=(0,1,2))
    lta = data
    my_array = np.vstack(my_array, lta)
```

I would expect the code for each file it reads to create the 3 column array (as the data in the text files) and then move to the next file (as defined in listing) and add the data in the same order - but it does not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be your real code -- there are a few obvious typos (`glob.blog`, for example).  Please always copy and paste.

But assuming that the code you're running uses `glob.glob`, then you'll probably need to iterate over a sorted version of the results to get the order you expect:

```
for infile in sorted(glob.glob("*.txt")):
    # do stuff here
```

This will sort lexicographically (in "alphabetical" order, so "10" < "2"); you can pass `sorted` a key function if you want something else.

Demonstration:

```
~/coding/fill$ more *.txt
::::::::::::::
0129A.txt
::::::::::::::
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
::::::::::::::
0201A.txt
::::::::::::::
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6

::::::::::::::
0210A.txt
::::::::::::::
7 8 9
7 8 9

::::::::::::::
0215A.txt
::::::::::::::
10 11 12
10 11 12
10 11 12
```

and

```
import os, glob
import numpy as np

datadirectory = '.'
os.chdir(datadirectory)
listing = sorted(os.listdir(datadirectory))
my_array = np.zeros(shape=(0,3))

for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
    dataset = open(infile).readlines()
    data = np.genfromtxt(dataset, usecols=(0,1,2))
    lta = data
    my_array = np.vstack([my_array, lta])

print my_array
```

gives me

```
[[  1.   2.   3.]
 [  1.   2.   3.]
 [  1.   2.   3.]
 [  4.   5.   6.]
 [  4.   5.   6.]
 [  4.   5.   6.]
 [  7.   8.   9.]
 [  7.   8.   9.]
 [ 10.  11.  12.]
 [ 10.  11.  12.]
 [ 10.  11.  12.]]
```

Comment: thanks for noticing the typos - I corrected 2 I found (my script is more complicated, I just wanted to have a simpler version posted) - I already sort the list, but even adding the sorted before glob (like you suggested) still get the same inconsistent (with the order) result

Comment: thanks for the demonstration - I can see that it works, and when I looked at my data probably worked there too (I will update the answer as correct when I verify it) - so there must be another problem with my code.....

Comment: you are correct; the data in the array are in the right order; the problem is with one of the functions - looking into it